# Count of open orders per week

Tags: mysql, datetime

I'm trying to find the number of orders that were open for each week. An order that is open for multiple weeks should be included in each week's count that it was open. The data looks something like below

```
id  open_dt               close_dt
1   2014-01-01 07:00:00   2014-01-01 07:00:00 
2   2014-01-01 07:00:00   2014-01-02 07:00:00 
3   2014-01-02 07:00:00   2014-01-09 07:00:00 
4   2014-01-08 07:00:00   NULL
```

NULL close_dt counts as still open and should appear in each week since it was opened

My query looks like below however it isn't returning the numbers I'm expecting:

```
SELECT YEAR(open_dt) AS year, WEEK(open_dt) AS week, count(*) 'open'
FROM table
WHERE open_dt >= week(open_dt)
OR 
(
    close_dt > week(open_dt)
    OR close_dt IS NULL
)
GROUP BY YEAR(open_dt), WEEK(open_dt)
```

I'm trying to get results like below:

```
year  week  open
2014  1     3
2014  2     2
2014  3     1
...
```

Appreciate any tips or guidance.

Comment: I found similar questions where the accepted solution was to join on a table containing the day/week numbers however I'm hoping to avoid that if possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a case where it helps to have a calendar table or list of weeks.  Let me assume that you have at least one open in each week:

```
select yw.y, yw.w, count(t.open_dt) as "Open"
from (select distinct year(open_dt) as y, week(open_dt) as w,
             year(open_dt) * 100 + week(open_dt) as yw
      from table t
     ) yw left outer join
     table t
     on yw.yw >= year(open_dt)*100 + week(open_dt) and
        (yw.yw <= year(close_dt)*100 + week(close_dt) or close_dt is null)
group by yw.y, yw.w
order by yw.y, yw.w;
```

Comment: I like how you included the week numbers as a subquery, never thought to try it like that.

Comment: I ran the query. It returned 0's for the first 100 or so rows and then 1010 for the remaining 50. Obviously not the correct results. However it did appear to return one row for each week containing data so that's a start.

Comment: This query didn't work for me but it got me close enough that I could solve the problem myself so I'll mark it as solution. Thanks.

Comment: @MrWednesday . . . I hope it was just the extra `*100` that I just removed.